# Customize the simple_form required label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have Googled this a bunch but I can't seem to find an obvious answer.  Simple Form adds the `<abbr title="required">*</abbr>` to your labels on required fields.  This is awesome - what would be 'awsomer' would be able to change this to something else.  What i had in mind is something as simple as as a font awesome icon like `<i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit that in [config/locales/simple_form.en.yml](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/locales/simple_form.en.yml) - uncomment the `simple_form.required.html` line and change it to your version, like:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    ...
    required:
      text: 'required'
      mark: '*'
      # You can uncomment the line below if you need to overwrite the whole required html.
      # When using html, text and mark won't be used.
      html: '<i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>'
```